# tufte document classes break with multiple authors

Tags: tufte

The following MWE (or MNWE) breaks with the error

`Extra \fi. <argument> ...rrenvir \else \@badend {tabular}\fi \expandafter \endgroup \if... l.5 \author{You \and me}`

Removing the \and command fixes it. `tufte-book` throws the same error. `article` or similar classes, of course, don't, and neither will the tufte classes break if the `\and` is removed.

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout}
\title{Your Paper}
\author{You \and me}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: `tufte` doesn't define `\and` you have to type `You and Me` or `You, me`. That all. If not you have to define `\author` by yourself.

Comment: @HarishKumar Indeed, especially if you can shed light on whether that's by design or just an omission, but I'll accept it as an answer either way unless someone else has more information

Comment: @PaulGessler I just did :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tufte` class doesn't define `\and`. Though I can not say whether it is by design or the authors missed it by accident precisely, I am inclined to believe that it is a design decision by the authors.

If you have to print two authors, you will have limited options like typing `You and Me` or `You, Me` by yourself. If not happy with this, you will have to define your own `\and`. But for this additional details like what that `\and` should do etc are needed and I beleive, is out of scope here.

Answer (score 0):

In LaTeX base, `\and` is defined as follows:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\and{%   % \begin{tabular}
  \end{tabular}%
  \hskip 1em \@plus.17fil%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{c}}%     % \end{tabular}
```

source: https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/blob/d3601236b649b7b280e32d494eae71d561f869a5/base/ltsect.dtx#L172-L175.

And, the same file shows that `\and` is used as a separator for all the authors. I'm not sure whether I fully understand it, but it seems that the authors are put each in a separate table.

So, depending on the project, you could try to copy this definition and get that to work. Or, do something simple like

```
\author{\noindent{Author 1}\\[3mm] \noindent{Author2}\\[3mm]}
```

**EDIT:** `\author` is defined as follows in the Tufte class:

```
\let\@author\@empty% suppress default latex.ltx ``no author'' warning
\renewcommand{\author}[2][]{%
  \ifthenelse{\isempty{#2}}{}{\gdef\@author{#2}}%
  \begingroup%
    % TODO store contents of \thanks command
    \renewcommand{\thanks}[1]{}% swallow \thanks contents
    \protected@xdef\thanklessauthor{#2}%
  \endgroup%
  \ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}%
    {\renewcommand{\plainauthor}{\thanklessauthor}}% use thankless author
    {\renewcommand{\plainauthor}{#1}}% use provided plain-text author
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\hypersetup}}%
    {}% hyperref is not loaded; do nothing
    {\hypersetup{pdfauthor={\plainauthor}}}% set the PDF metadata author
}
```

source: https://github.com/Tufte-LaTeX/tufte-latex/blob/efb8c8e836890bad71fb5834acdd316ebde6db12/tufte-common.def#L592-L606.